# How to split a systemtap script into multiple files?

Tags: systemtap

I'm writing a medium-sized systemtap script with clearly separable parts. I would like to split it into multiple files. I see two possibilities for doing this, but not ideal. Is there an official way or maybe a convention?

### 1. concatenate manually and read script from stdin

```
cat *.stp | stap -
```

### 2. use an import function

Systemtap always imports whole files, so this should work:

#### main.stp

```
probe begin {
    import_child();
}
```

#### child.stp

```
function import_child() {
    // using this function imports the whole file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter method is the one used by the tapset library.  Since you're creating your own analogous library, feel free to use the same one.  `stap -I /path/to/your/tapset/directory` will add it to the search path.  You don't have to use a function to create the cross-file reference; a global variable or probe alias is good enough too.